# Angular 8, how to load a module/component from an external server

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I have an angular 8 application and I would like to load "plugin" modules/components from an external server that is hosting.

Blogs like this: https://dev.to/binarysort/manually-lazy-load-components-in-angular-8-ffi talk about lazy loading modules in angular 8 using "import".

IE:

```
import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
```

However I would like to load a module from another server:

```
import('https://modules.com/some.module.ts').then(m => m.SomeModule)
```

When I try this I get an error:

```
Cannot find module 'https://modules.com/some.module.js'
    at services lazy ^.*$ namespace object:11
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:396)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:26256)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:395)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:153)
    at zone.js:894
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:198)
```

Is it possible in angular 8 to load a typescript or javascript module or component from an external server with "import"?

Comment: I think the best way to get a third-party module into your app would be to use npm / yarn. Is the module you are looking for not available by those means?

Comment: Based on a quick search, best I can find is no, you can't import like this.  You might be able to inject the script to the dom, but considering this is Angular specific I doubt it would work.

Comment: @PhilNinan agree in a general case for deps that are hosted on npm/yarn.  However I don't have that option, plugins are hosted and are dynamic.  In my case I need discover the plugins from the external server at runtime and load them.

Comment: @Phix I think it's possible using SystemJS.  However I saw that angular 8 allows dynamic imports so I thought I would explore that first.  I have not tried SystemJS yet.